# Export Powershell 5 enum declaration from a Module

Tags: powershell, enums, powershell-5.0, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-module

I have an enum type defined within a module. How do I export it to be accessible from outside once the module has been loaded?

```
enum fruits {
 apple
 pie
}

function new-fruit {
    Param(
        [fruits]$myfruit
    )
    write-host $myfruit
}
```

My advanced function takes the enum instead of the `ValidateSet` which works if the enum is available, but fails if it isn't.

**Update:**
Separating it into a ps1 and dot-sourcing it (ScriptsToProcess) works, however I would wish that there's a cleaner way.

Comment: See [how to export a class in powershell v5 module](//stackoverflow.com/a/38701492) - add `using module moduleName` after import

Comment: @wOxxOm `The using module command imports the module and also loads the class definitions` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.1#example-2---load-classes-from-a-script-module

Answer (score 15):

Ran into the same issue trying to use/export an enumeration from a nested module (.psm1) on 5.0.x.

Managed to get it working by using `Add-Type` instead:

```
Add-Type @'
public enum fruits {
    apple,
    pie
}
'@
```

You should then be able to use

```
[fruits]::apple
```

Comment: +1 because this is the best method if you depend on module autoloading feature, otherwise we'd have to manually do `using module ...`

Answer (score 11):

You can access the enums after loading the module using the `using module ...` command.

For example:

MyModule.psm1

```
enum MyPriority {
    Low = 0
    Medium = 1
    high = 2
}
function Set-Priority {
  param(
    [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Priority')] [MyPriority] $priority
  )
  Write-Host $Priority
}  
Export-ModuleMember -function Set-Priority
```

Make:

```
New-ModuleManifest MyModule.psd1 -RootModule 'MyModule.psm1' -FunctionsToExport '*'
```

Then in Powershell...

```
Import-Module .\MyModule\MyModule.psd1
PS C:\Scripts\MyModule> [MyPriority] $p = [MyPriority ]::High
Unable to find type [MyPriority].
At line:1 char:1
+ [MyPriority] $p = [MyPriority ]::High
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MyPriority:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

PS C:\Scripts\MyModule> using module .\MyModule.psd1
PS C:\Scripts\MyModule> [MyPriority] $p = [MyPriority ]::High
PS C:\Scripts\MyModule> $p
high
```

Comment: In short: `enum` and `class` definitions defined in PowerShell modules are only visible to importers of such modules if [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using#module-syntax) rather than [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Import-Module) is used.

Answer (score 2):

When you get classes, enum or any .Net type in a module and you want to export them you have to use the `using` key word in the script where you want to import it, otherwise only `cmlet` are going to be imported.

Answer (score 2):

I see your question said you were looking for a cleaner way than dot sourcing scripts or using the ScriptsToProcess, but this works for me.

**Step 1:**

- Create a .PS1 file in your module. I called mine `Enumerations.ps1`, and placed the file in the root folder of my module.
- In this new file place your enumeration statements

  ```
   ENUM DeathStarPlans {
       Reactor = 0
       Trench  = 1
       SuperSecretExhaustPort = 2
       }
  ```

**Step 2**

- Update your .PSD1 manifest file to include the `ScriptsToProcess` option
- Refer to the path to your enumeration file. This path is relative to where your .psd1 file is located.

  ```
   ScriptsToProcess = @(".\Enumerations.ps1")
  ```

**Step 3**

- Import your module, this may require closing powershell and reopening if you have classes or other types created.

  ```
   Import-Module "module name" -force
  ```

**Step 4**

- Use your enums

  ```
   [DeathStarPlans]::SuperSecretExhaustPort
  ```

Answer (score -3):

This looks to be an issue somewhere in the 5.0.x release of PowerShell.

I had the issue on 5.0.10105.0

However, this is working fine in the 5.1.x release.