# PS6+ How to export enumerators in a module?

Tags: powershell

I have a module where I define enumerators. Currently, I have the enumerator definitions in a `ps1` file, which I dot-source in the `psm1` module file, like this:

`Enumerators.ps1`

```
enum Fruits {
    apple
    pear
    orange
    banana
}
```

`MyModule.psm1`

```
. Fruits.ps1
```

I was doing the same with classes, but I learned about the [`Types.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) file for defining types, so I'll be moving my class definitions into there. Is there a comparable method for defining enumerators? Microsoft's documentation doesn't mention an "enumerator" member tag for `Types.ps1xml`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348069/export-powershell-5-enum-declaration-from-a-module), which is from PS v5--I'm wondering if something's changed with PS6/7?

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by moving the class definition to the types file? The `types.ps1xml` is for adding ETS members to a type not a place where you would store a type definition

Comment: In that case, maybe I misunderstood the purpose of `types.ps1xml`. So, does that mean that dot-sourcing for enums and classes is still the best method?

Comment: The reco I would give you is to if you want to have separated ps1 files then use a module that would merge all files into a single psm1 file. You can look into ModuleBuilder for example. You will also want to have a build file for your module with steps for building and testing and for that you can look into `Invoke-Build`

Comment: "So, does that mean that dot-sourcing for enums and classes is still the best method?" personally, I would merge all files into a single `psm1` but that is an alternative. The common pattern is to have a module folder where you have a private and public folder and a psd1 (no psm1) then ModuleBuilder targets that folder and merges all files into a single `psm1` with its corresponding `psd1`. This process is all done by your `build.ps1` file and invoked by your yaml pipeline at the moment of publishing to the PS Gallery or whatever